# Expansion $(x+{\frac{1}{x}})^4 (x-{\frac{1}{x}})^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic, fractions

> Expand $(x+{\frac{1}{x}})^4 (x-{\frac{1}{x}})^2$

Right now, I am able to expand this expression by simplifying it to:

$\frac{(x^2+1)^4 (x^2-1)^2}{x^6}$

I used the formula $(a+b)^2$ and $(a-b)^2$ a bunch of times to arrive at the answer. But, is there any simpler/smarter way to do this?

Comment: You are asked to expand the formula which you have not done!

Comment: @copper.hat I'm not sure I understand what you mean.

Comment: $(a+b)^2$ is not expanded. $a^2+2ab + b^2$ is.

Comment: @copper.hat I'm just saying that I used the formulas to further simplify my expression..

Comment: But you made it more complicated, so no, you didn't.

Comment: @copper.hat If you could provide a simpler answer, that would be great :)

Comment: See John's answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following procedure, I believe, is somewhat simpler

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\left(x+{\frac{1}{x}}\right)^4 \left(x-{\frac{1}{x}}\right)^2 & = \left(x+{\frac{1}{x}}\right)^2\left(x+{\frac{1}{x}}\right)^2\left(x-{\frac{1}{x}}\right)^2 \\
& = \left(x+{\frac{1}{x}}\right)^2\left(\left(x+{\frac{1}{x}}\right)\left(x-{\frac{1}{x}}\right)\right)^2 \\
& = \left(x+{\frac{1}{x}}\right)^2\left(x^2 - \frac{1}{x^2}\right)^2 \\
& = \left(\left(x+{\frac{1}{x}}\right)\left(x^2 - \frac{1}{x^2}\right)\right)^2 \\
& = \left(x^3 - \frac{1}{x} + x - \frac{1}{x^3}\right)^2 \\
& = \left(\left(x^3 - \frac{1}{x^3}\right) + \left(x - \frac{1}{x}\right)\right)^2 \\
& = \left(x^3 - \frac{1}{x^3}\right)^2 + 2\left(x^3 - \frac{1}{x^3}\right)\left(x - \frac{1}{x}\right) + \left(x - \frac{1}{x}\right)^2 \\
& = x^6 - 2 + \frac{1}{x^6} + 2\left(x^4 - x^2 - \frac{1}{x^2} + \frac{1}{x^4}\right) + x^2 - 2 + \frac{1}{x^2} \\
& = x^6 + 2x^4 - x^2 - 4 -\frac{1}{x^2} + \frac{2}{x^4} + \frac{1}{x^6}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{1}\label{eq1}$$

Answer (score 2):

$$(x+{\frac{1}{x}})^4 (x-{\frac{1}{x}})^2= \frac {(x^2+1)^4(x^2-1)^2}{x^6}=$$

$$\frac {(x^4-1)^2(x^2+1)^2}{x^6} =\frac {(x^8-2x^4+1)(x^4+2x^2+1)}{x^6}=$$

$$\frac{x^{12} +2x^{10} -x^8-4x^6-x^4+2x^2+1}{x^6}=$$

$$x^{6} +2x^{4} -x^2-4-\frac {1}{x^2}+\frac {2}{x^4}+\frac {1}{x^6}$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $y=\frac1{x}$.  Then,

\begin{align}
(x+\frac1{x})^4(x-\frac1{x})^2&=(x+y)^4(x-y)^2\\
&=(x+y)^2(x+y)^2(x-y)^2\\
&=(x+y)^2(x^2-y^2)^2\\
&=\big((x+y)(x^2-y^2)\big)^2\\
&=(x^3+x^2y-xy^2-y^3)^2\\
&=(x^3+x-\frac1{x}-\frac1{x^3})^2\\
&=\bigg(\frac{x^6+x^4-x^2-1}{x^3}\bigg)^2\\
&=\frac{x^{12} + 2x^{10} - x^8 - 4 x^6 - x^4 + 2 x^2 + 1}{x^6}
\end{align}

(or $x^6+2x^4-x^2-4-\frac1{x^2}+\frac2{x^4}+\frac1{x^6}$, if you'd like).

Comment: I think your coefficients of ${1 \over x^2}$, ${1 \over x^4}$
 are incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Observe:

$(x - \frac{1}{x})^2 = x^2 - 2 + \frac {1}{x^2}\\
(x + \frac{1}{x})^2 = x^2 + 2 + \frac {1}{x^2}\\
(x - \frac{1}{x})^2= (x + \frac 1x)^2 - 4$

We make this substitution in the original expression

$(x + \frac 1x)^4(x - \frac{1}{x})^2)\\
(x + \frac 1x)^4((x + \frac{1}{x})^2 - 4)\\
(x + \frac 1x)^6 - 4(x + \frac{1}{x})^4$

Note, we are doing something not entirely unlike $\sin^2 x = 1 - \cos^2 x$ here.

And use the binomial expansion on each term above.

$(x + \frac 1x)^6 = (x^6 + \frac1{x^6}) + 6 (x^4 + \frac1{x^4}) + 15 (x^2 + \frac1{x^2}) + 20\\
(x + \frac 1x)^4 = (x^4 + \frac1{x^4}) + 4 (x^2 + \frac1{x^2}) + 6$

$(x + \frac 1x)^6 - 4(x + \frac 1x)^4 = (x^6 + \frac1{x^6}) + 2 (x^4 + \frac1{x^4}) - (x^2 + \frac1{x^2}) - 4$